# WSO2 BPEL add partnerlink cause [UndeclaredXsdType] Attempt to reference undeclared XSD type

Tags: eclipse, namespaces, wso2, bpel

I am using wso2bps-3.2.0 and Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2, buildId 4.3.2.M20140221-1700 with WSO2 BPEL plug-in 2.0.0
I create two partner links and there weren't compilation errors. When I added third partnerlink I got CompilationException: error: [CompilationErrors] Compilation completed with 4 error(s)
error: [UndeclaredXsdType] Attempt to reference undeclared XSD type
error: [UndeclaredVariable] Attempt to reference undeclared variable

I tried to separate variables into scopes but no luck.
I searched on internet and I found that could be problem with namespaces.

Here is namespaces before partnerlink adding

```
xmlns:ns0="http://webservice.rpdservice.sk/"  
xmlns:xsd="http://schemas.data.org/2004/07/Data.Model"  
xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Here is namespaces after third partnerlink adding

```
xmlns:ns0="http://webservice.rpdservice.sk/"  
xmlns:xsd="http://schemas.data.org/2004/07/Data.Model"  
xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/"
```

Undeclared types are the same one. Undeclared variable is only request variable.
What can I do?

I find out that problem was in third partnerlink xsd definition

Comment: it is very hard provide an answer without looking BPEL artifact. One possible error could be you are referring a xsd or wsdl which is outside of the artifacts.

Comment: I understand. It is hard to show whole project. There is lot of schemas. Finally I found problem in XSD schema but definitely different from reported in log.